# .NET library to convert KML to WKT?

Tags: .net, kml, well-known-text

Anyone know of a free OpenSource .NET library i could use to convert KML to WKT?

I know i can use openlayers and there are many JavaScript possibilities, but i need to do this on the back-end.

Comment: SharpMap is an easy-to-use mapping library for use in web and desktop applications. http://www.sharpgis.net/category/SharpMap.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i'm using post GIS, I ended up having it do it for me:

If i need two KML feature's converted, i'll send it a select like the following:

```
SELECT  ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromKML('<Polygon >
  <outerBoundaryIs>
    <LinearRing>
      <coordinates>
                    120.801170655354,14.632489189195,0
                    120.782956111463,14.5427894930054,0
                    120.76474480255,14.4530886861418,0
                    120.925219414103,14.4220920136416,0
                    120.943496765891,14.5117984961193,0
                    120.961777812394,14.6015038368517,0
                    120.801170655354,14.632489189195,0
                  </coordinates>
    </LinearRing>
  </outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>')), ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromKML('<Polygon >
  <outerBoundaryIs>
    <LinearRing>
      <coordinates>
                    121.087312420981,14.6013782055702,0
                    121.071223131928,14.5142178677531,0
                    121.244070778376,14.4838207663532,0
                    121.260233278214,14.571006143522,0
                    121.087312420981,14.6013782055702,0
                  </coordinates>
    </LinearRing>
  </outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>'))
```

Result:

```
"POLYGON((120.801170655354 14.632489189195,120.782956111463 14.5427894930054,120.76474480255 14.4530886861418,120.925219414103 14.4220920136416,120.943496765891 14.5117984961193,120.961777812394 14.6015038368517,120.801170655354 14.632489189195))";"POLYGON((121.087312420981 14.6013782055702,121.071223131928 14.5142178677531,121.244070778376 14.4838207663532,121.260233278214 14.571006143522,121.087312420981 14.6013782055702))"
```

Answer (score 6):

How about using GDAL's OGR .NET bindings?

http://bjarte.com/post/gdal-in-csharp

and its KML driver through libkml 
http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_libkml.html

Alternatively, you could use libkml directly.

Comment: I don't see any KML readers in the GDAL gone wild project. Am i missing something?

Comment: Ugh, you are right. The libkml drivers came this year and those are from last year. Can you check if the OSGeo4W binaries have the libkml dll in it?

Comment: Nothing from what i can see.

Answer (score 3):

Your other option is to use the [NetTopologySuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/) which is a port from the Java version, it supports WKT Reading/Writing.

We've then taken the Kml xsd, using the provided ms tools converted it to classes which the xml serialiser understands and then walked the tree converting the nodes we cared about into NTS IGeometry that the rest of our system used.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: I've created the classes from xsd now...Do you know which dlls int he NTS have the WKT read/write capabilities?

Comment: I use GisSharpBlog.NetTopologySuite.IO WKTWriter/WKTReader

Comment: How did you go with it?

Comment: Actually, I'm using something very unconventional, but it works like a charm and it's very easy, and it's what i need. I'll post an update soon. Basically i'm having my PostGIS database do it for me.

Comment: (+1) for trying and giving me the most likely alternative though.